# Issue in Reading JSON File in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to read this file in java using `map(ObjectMapper and TypeReference)` but `map` is picking only one data i.e. `name: "David Roberts"`, `slug: "david-robets"` and `assigned: "assigned"`.

I also tried using `JsonParser`, but didn't get the appropriate result.

Any suggestion on this please:

```
{
  "name": "David Roberts",
  "slug": "david-roberts",
  "assigned": "assigned"
},
{
  "name": "Robert Chang",
  "slug": "robert-chang",
  "assigned": "assigned"
},
{
  "name": "Chris Curtis",
  "slug": "chris.curtis",
  "assigned": "assigned",
  "fileId": "1370206"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "map is picking only one data"?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: are you looping it to read all records?

Comment: is this the complete JSON? seems you are missing a `}`

Comment: Map<String, Object> map = null;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

   map = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\Users.json"),
     new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
     });

   System.out.println(map);

Comment: {
      "name": "David Roberts",
      "slug": "david-roberts",
      "assigned": "assigned"
    },
Only this value I am getting in map.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong json file. 
The right format is:

```
[{
  "name": "David Roberts",
  "slug": "david-roberts",
  "assigned": "assigned"
},
{
  "name": "Robert Chang",
  "slug": "robert-chang",
  "assigned": "assigned"
},
{
  "name": "Chris Curtis",
  "slug": "chris.curtis",
  "assigned": "assigned",
  "fileId": "1370206"
}]
```

Comment: After changing JSON format, I am getting this exception
JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token

Answer (score 0):

If you want all values then json should be like this.

```
{"values":[{
          "name": "David Roberts",
          "slug": "david-roberts",
          "assigned": "assigned"
        },
        {
          "name": "Robert Chang",
          "slug": "robert-chang",
          "assigned": "assigned"
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris Curtis",
          "slug": "chris.curtis",
          "assigned": "assigned",
          "fileId": "1370206"
        }]

    }
```